# run gcloud script in cloud build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-build

I would like to have a cloud source repo which contains:-

- The cloudbuild.yaml file.
- A gcloud shell script (to create infra, eg a VM).

Is it possible to set things up where on a push to that repo, cloud build runs the shell script? Is there an example of this anywhere? The only examples I can find are for Python or Node.js

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's totally possible to run shell scripts within your cloud build pipeline.

Here you can find a few examples: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/run-bash-scripts

Within Cloud Build, there is also a [built in gcloud image](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/gcloud) where you could directly run gcloud commands. Simple examples:

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: ['compute', 'instances', 'add-metadata', 'example-instance','--metadata startup-script-url=gs://bucket/file']
```

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: [
        'deployment-manager',
        'deployments',
        'create', 
        'lgwm-$SHORT_SHA', 
        '--template', 
        'vm_template.jinja',
        '--properties',
        'zone:${_ZONE}'
        ]
```